# Stucked on "resolving dependencies"

Tags: flutter, intellij-idea

I'm new in flutter and even though I thoroughly followed the instructions from YouTube I do get stuck up in resolving dependencies when creating flutter project on either CLI or VS Code Are there any solutions for this problem? I've tried waiting for more than 30 minutes to finish the "resolving dependencies".

I've tried reinstalling the flutter SDK, the "pub get" (which still do get stuck up in dependencies), also I've tried to develop flutter using IntelliJ, it also gets stuck in "Creating flutter project"

[*flutter doctor* result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYc99.png)

Comment: Can you share the flutter doctor result

Comment: i dont know how to reply but i've edited my post and added there the picture

Comment: Have you tried `path/to/sdkmanager --install “cmdline-tools;latest"` and `flutter doctor --android-licenses` commands as mentioned in flutter doctor result?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Android Studio
- Goto tools-> SDK Manager-> Android SDK -> SDK tools
- Install Android SDK command line tools from there

[image]

Then run following command. It will prompt you to accept the Android SDK licenses. Follow the prompts to accept the licenses.

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Then specify the path of Chrome using the CHROME_EXECUTABLE environment variable like below. Remember to replace the path with the actual location of your Chrome executable.

```
set CHROME_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Finally download [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). Make sure to select the "Desktop development with C++" during the installation

Hope this will be helpful for you. Let me know if you need any further clarification.